# How to create a sql view (CREATE VIEW) in sqlite(android) and query?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

So I have a table and I want to create another table using "CREATE VIEW" from sql.
I need to make a copy of the table that I am working with so I can use it 2x. My sql query would have to be like this:

```
SELECT A.time AS Start, B.time AS Stop
FROM time A, time B
WHERE A.id+1=B.id
AND A.bool=1
AND B.bool=0
```

my initial table is:

```
    String sql="create table "+TABLE+" ( "+C_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
+C_TIME+" TEXT, "+C_BOOL+" NUMERIC)";
```

so anyone has any ideea where (in my code) I can create the view and how do I query it in android?

I can provide code if needed

Thank you :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Based on [this](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html), you would create the view with the following statement:

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS 
    SELECT A.time AS Start, B.time AS Stop
    FROM time A, time B
    WHERE A.id+1=B.id
        AND A.bool=1
        AND B.bool=0
```

You can create it right after you create the "base" table.

You can query it just like you would query any other table.

Comment: I know it sounds stupid but I have a question: does sql know that A.time and B.time are rows? if not, how do I do that. (sorry, but i am pretty new with sql)

Comment: sqlite knows that A.Time and B.time are columns. Just to be clear, your `time` table has a column `time`?

Comment: my 'time' table has a column named 'times'

Comment: a column named `times` or `time`?

Comment: i think I need to change the name... it is confusing. the column is with s